# Facebook like box images distorted

Tags: image, height, facebook-likebox, distortion

I'm using the FB like box widget on my website. I noticed that bigger images published on FB are appearing distorted in the box.

I'm seeing that the css responsible for this is:

```
.uiScaledImageContainer img {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
 }
```

Is there a way I can force `height: auto` in my css?
Apparently anything I declare for this element in my sytlesheet is ignored, even using `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the CSS in Facebook's iFrame. 
I'm having the same issue but there is another bit of code that is overiding the "height:100%" with "height: auto" and i'm getting the same outcome. If I change the min-height to "auto" it seems to fix it.

The original code is:

```
.fan_box .uiStreamStory .uiStreamAttachments .photoRedesignAspect .img, .fan_box .uiStreamStory .uiStreamAttachments .photoRedesignCover .img, .fan_box .photoRedesign .img, .uiStreamStory .videoRedesign .uiVideoThumb img {
height: auto;
left: 0 !important;
width: 100%;
```

And

```
.uiScaledImageContainer img {
height: 100%; <!-- this is being overwritten -->
min-height: 100%;
position: relative;
```

Now we just need someone to update facebook's likebox.php. 
Surprisingly, IE is the only browser that this isn't a problem. And for some reason firefox doesn't load the app altogether...

Answer (score 0):

since nothing has changed until now here are some more details I found out to this problem:

- It only appears to me on images that are in an album, not single
  images that were uploaded in a post.
- It appears to me in chrome browser and on iphone and android devices, not on firefox and 
  internet explorer.

Maybe that helps.